# C# How to maintain the path as in string without replacing double slash

Tags: c#

I have a string with value

```
"\\test\mxf\123456\123456789.abc"
```

When I use

```
var x= @"\\test\mxf\123456\123456789.abc"
```

I am getting an output as

```
"\\test\\mxf\\123456\\123456789"
```

How to get the string as a path i.e `"\\test\mxf\123456\123456789.abc"`
without the double slashes getting replaced?

Comment: That sounds extremely unlikely to me. I suspect you're *actually* seeing `"\\\\test\\mxf\\123456\\123456789.abc"` but that you're seeing it in the debugger, which automatically escapes strings for you - in other words, the *actual* string content is as expected.

Comment: @ is a `verbose` string which does not require escaping the backslash, whist a regular string does. @"\" is a legal string containing one slash, whilst "\\" is a legal non verbose string containing one slash - it needs escaping.

Comment: Thanks. I think because i was checking in debugger, i had this weird issue. Thanks

Comment: downvotes should not be allowed without a comment... there's nothing wrong with asking a question because the debugger confused you. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Console to check strings and not the debugger :

```
var x= @"\\test\mxf\123456\123456789.abc"

Console.WriteLine(x); // output is \\test\mxf\123456\123456789.abc
```

Comment: Ok thanks. You are right. I am checking it in the debugger

Comment: The console output is `\\test\mxf\123456\123456789.abc`.

Comment: But when i assign the value to a property and write in json, still getting additional \\. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var x = "\"" + @"\\test\mxf\123456\123456789.abc" + "\"";;

Console.WriteLine(x);
```